# What effect does giving the Rage action additional traits (e.g. "arcane and evocation") confer?

Tags: barbarian, rage, pathfinder-2e

Several of the Barbarian Instinct Abilities modify the traits of the Rage action.

For example:

> Draconic Rage (Instinct Ability)
>
> While raging, you can increase the additional damage
> from Rage from 2 to 4 and change its damage type to
> match that of your dragon’s breath weapon instead of the
> damage type for your weapon or unarmed attack. **If you
> do this, your Rage action gains the arcane and evocation
> traits, as well as the trait matching the damage type.**

As well, the arcane trait only seems to indicate the effect is magical in nature:

> arcane (trait) This magic comes from the arcane tradition, which is built on logic
> and rationality. Anything with this trait is magical. 299

What mechanics in the game (if any) interact with this modification of the Rage action?

Rage isn't a spell, so it can't be dispelled. *Antimagic field* doesn't seem to interact with abilities such as this. Rage mainly just modifies weapon damage, so its not like resistance is interacting with the traits of Rage, but rather its modified damage type. Other class Feats tied to the instinct that might have saves (e.g. the dragon's breath) have the traits, and it makes sense in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Antimagic Field and detect magic

From the [Antimagic Field description](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=14):

> You repel all magic from the target area, preventing spells **and
>   other magic** from functioning...and no one inside can cast spells or
>   use **magic abilities**...

As you noted, the Arcane trait turns the rage action into a magical ability, and its effect into a magical effect. This means that, while inside the an antimagic field, you could not start raging, and the ongoing effect of a previously taken rage action would be supressed.

Also, your rage would count as a magic effect (of the evocation school) for detect magic and similar effects.